# Google cloud plaform [Python] >>> from google.cloud import storage / ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, package, backend, http-status-code-503

When i try deploy script on google cloud plaform while i use 'from google.cloud import storage' i recrive on webpage 'Service Unavailable' and some 503 errors in logs. When i just run script in console its works.

Communicates looks like that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from google.cloud import storage
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

```
The request failed because either the HTTP response was malformed or connection to the instance had an error. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#malformed-response-or-connection-error
```

also my requirements.txt file

```
beautifulsoup4==4.11.1
cachetools==5.2.0
certifi==2022.9.24
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.5
Flask==2.1.2
google==3.0.0
google-api-core==2.10.2
google-auth==2.14.1
google-cloud-core==2.3.2
google-cloud-storage==2.6.0
google-crc32c==1.5.0
google-resumable-media==2.4.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.56.4
idna==3.4
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
protobuf==4.21.9
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
requests==2.28.1
rsa==4.9
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.2.post1
urllib3==1.26.12
Werkzeug==2.1.2
```

I tried:
upgrade\update package
reinstall packages
put google folder with packages directly in webpage folder

I expecting, just use this package

Comment: You deployed your script in which service ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun i dont sure about what you ask? I deploy scritp on google cloud plaform right after i pulled it from my repo

Comment: 1. i create working app on vsc (without errors)
2. i push it to my repo with libs from my vsc env
3. i pull it to my GCP folder
4. i try deploy with this libs- this same error
5. i delate this libs
6. i create bash env for this folder
7. i download packages i need
8 i deploy again- this same error
9. bonus : i also try without env from core packages from GCP- this same error